# How to delete hibernation files on deb based system

Tags: command-line, files, kali-linux

I have a Kali VM that is seized up, during booting it says "resuming from hibernation" and does not progress. There is no disk i/o. I am wondering if it is possible to completely delete the files related to hibernation in attempt to force a normal boot. If  so where are these files located, or is there another way to keep the system from trying to resume from a hibernated state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your VM includes a Linux swap partition, it might contain the hibernation data, so there will not be a file to delete.

Anyway, if you can access the GRUB bootloader of the VM, add the boot option `noresume` to avoid any attempts to resume from hibernation and execute a full normal start-up instead.

(Some virtualization methods that use paravirtualization may skip GRUB entirely and instead start the VM's operating system in some other way. In that case, you would have to use some other method to enter boot options, and that would be specific to the virtualization system you are using. Since you did not say what virtualization system you are using, this may or may not apply to you.)

Comment: Seems like a much more streamlined way to fix the issue than the route I took.

Answer (score 1):

To temporarily bypass this issue, I ran

```
swapoff -a
```

Then, I commented out the swap partition's uuid in `/etc/fstab`
Then, I commented out the swap partition's uuid in `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`

and finally

```
update-grub
update-initramfs -u
```

This worked like a charm

Comment: Please help its so urgent.

Comment: @DavidKariuki https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?44514-Stuck-on-resuming-from-hibernation-on-boot-up Apparently I'm not the only one with this issue, other people might find it useful

Answer (score 0):

At times the problem is not in the grub or UUID. This also happens when you are out of storage space. There will be no write space left thus resuming from hibernation will freeze.

When you get to that error, you can click on `alt+ f2/f3/f7` or `ctrl+alt+ f2/f3/f7` to open terminal. Login to your account or root using terminal.

Then run the command `sudo df -h` to check on storage space. In my case I had no space on my `/dev/sda1` so check on free space on the drives in the list.

If you are out of space, please try deleting some files to get some considerable amount of space.

After that you can click on `alt+f1` or `ctrl+alt+f1` and wait for the login gui to appear or type `reboot in the terminal to reboot`

Comment: was out of space, but freeing up space from recovery mode terminal didn't solve the issue